# Detect Mean Change Years in a Monthly Time Series in R

Tags: r, statistics, time-series, probability

I am interested in finding the multiple mean change years in the trend of a monthly data, i.e. the years in which mean changes significantly. I came across an R package [changepoint](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/changepoint/index.html) and formulated my problem as

```
library(changepoint)
df <- read.csv("test.csv")
tdf <- ts(df$x, frequency = 12, start = c(1991, 1))
d <-  decompose(tdf)
tr <- as.vector(d$trend)
tr2 <- tr[13:432]
cp <- cpt.mean(tr2,penalty="SIC",pen.value=0.05, method="BinSeg", Q=80,  class=FALSE)
plot(p)
```

Now here it throws an error

```
Error in 1:nseg : NA/NaN argument
```

Problems:

1. When I use `method = "AMOC"` (at most one change), it gives me on point. But `method = "BinSeg"` is not working for some reason.
2. When `method = "PELT"` is used, so many change points come into the picture, which certainly not a good case, as I went through this [link](http://www.r-bloggers.com/changepoint-analysis-of-time-series/).

So in a nutshell, which method is to be used to get mean-change years, my data can be accessed from [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B1AkoLkOUzvLTkJfMVdlUFZIY0U/view?usp=sharing). If any other method is better than these methods and available in R, please suggest.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what exactly is the problem with the `"BinSeg"` method but the many changepoints that `"PELT"` detects are caused by removing seasonality *and* remainder. If you want to seasonally adjust the data prior to `changepoint` modeling, then you should not just extract the trend. In case of `decompose()` this is a moving average and thus is highly correlated with seemingly low variance.

You might consider using the `bfast` package which provides *"breaks for additive season and trend"* decompositions. This allows you to capture changes in either season or trend. It builds on the structural change (or changepoint) tests in the `strucchange` package.

One possible way for analyzing your data would be to just use a simple model without any trend and with a harmonic (sine/cosine) seasonal pattern. The harmonic regressors for various frequencies (default = 3) can be easily set up with the `bfastpp()` function:

```
df <- read.csv("test_22.csv")
tdf <- ts(df$x, frequency = 12, start = c(1991, 1))
df <- bfastpp(tdf)
names(df)
## [1] "time"     "response" "trend"    "season"   "harmon"
```

Fitting the full-sample model without any structural changepoints yield:

```
m <- lm(response ~ harmon, data = df)
summary(m)
## Call:
## lm(formula = response ~ harmon, data = df)
## 
## Residuals:
##      Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max 
## -132.297  -13.619   -0.909   11.701  156.339 
## 
## Coefficients:
##             Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
## (Intercept)   97.248      1.160  83.857  < 2e-16 ***
## harmoncos1  -114.401      1.640 -69.754  < 2e-16 ***
## harmoncos2    46.924      1.640  28.612  < 2e-16 ***
## harmoncos3   -15.276      1.640  -9.314  < 2e-16 ***
## harmonsin1   -29.878      1.640 -18.218  < 2e-16 ***
## harmonsin2    30.348      1.640  18.505  < 2e-16 ***
## harmonsin3    -7.165      1.640  -4.369 1.56e-05 ***
## ---
## Signif. codes:  0 '***' 0.001 '**' 0.01 '*' 0.05 '.' 0.1 ' ' 1
## 
## Residual standard error: 24.44 on 437 degrees of freedom
## Multiple R-squared:  0.9367,    Adjusted R-squared:  0.9358 
## F-statistic:  1077 on 6 and 437 DF,  p-value: < 2.2e-16
```

The time series of residuals and its ACF both look fairly ok as well

```
plot(ts(residuals(m), start = 1991, frequency = 12)
acf(residuals(m))
```

[image: tsdiag]

Not surprisingly, various structural change tests are non-significant then, e.g., a MOSUM-type test or the supLM test. All other tests I tried also yielded no significant changes.

```
sctest(m, functional = maxMOSUM(0.25))
##         M-fluctuation test
## 
## data:  m
## f(efp) = 1.3143, p-value = 0.2315
sctest(m, functional = supLM(0.1))
##         M-fluctuation test
## 
## data:  m
## f(efp) = 17.666, p-value = 0.2162
```

You can also use the function `bfast()` for a similar type of analysis in one go. This also stops in the first iteration because it detects no break.

```
bf <- bfast(tdf, season = "harmon", max.iter = 100)
plot(bf)
```

[image: bfast]

See `citation("strucchange")` and `citation("bfast")` for references with more details.

Comment: Dear Achim, thanks for reply. I also found `ecp` an R package. In which different algorithms require a parameter `alpha=2` (set as two) to detect multiple changes. Will it be good to use `e.cp3o` in  `ecp` for my data. Please suggest. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Yes, there is a number of packages that can deal with changepoints including: `bfast`, `bcp`, `changepoint`, `cpm`, `ecp`, `segmented`, `strucchange`, among others. The focus is not always the same: some do significance testing others mainly changepoint estimation. Some detect changepoints ex post others sequentially online. Some are nonparametric, or based on regression models, or Bayesian etc.

Comment: The only problem with this algorithm is different values of K in `e.cp3o` generate different values of change points. Please suggest on the optimal choice of K.

Comment: I'm not an expert on the `ecp` package. Please consult their documentation first, e.g., http://www.jstatsoft.org/v62/i07/. If this doesn't resolve your problems, consider contacting the authors.